Why I get extra text when using bs4 and lxml
I have div object
<div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="21.11.2024 20:17:23 UTC+07:00">
20:17
       </div>

       <div class="from_name">
Cheki_FNS 
       </div>

       <div class="text">
Cash receipt received: from <strong>Komandor trading network</strong> (LLC &quot;TS KOMANDOR&quot;)
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

I use next code:

with open("messages.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    html_content = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "xml")

div_text = soup.find("div", class_="text")


if div_text:
    print(div_text.get_text())
else:
    print("Error, class text not find")

I was expecting get next line:
"A cash receipt has been received: from the Komandor Trading Network (TS Komandor LLC)"

, but I get:
"20:17  Cheki_FNS A cash receipt has been received: from the Komandor Trading Network (TS Komandor LLC)". 

Is it really a problem that some part of the text goes beyond the scope of div objects?

Your selection works correct based on your example, so ensure you have the exact input from your file.
Here are some points you should also check:

check, if in some files there is another <div> with class of text
do not use the xml parser it is HTML -> Overview Parser
may use css selectors, if you need to chain elements and its attributes

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = '''
<div class="body">
       <div class="pull_right date details" title="21.11.2024 20:17:23 UTC+07:00">
20:17
       </div>
       <div class="from_name">
Cheki_FNS 
       </div>
       <div class="text">
Cash receipt received: from <strong>Komandor trading network</strong> (LLC &quot;TS KOMANDOR&quot;)
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
'''
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    
print(soup.find("div", class_="text").get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one("div.text").get_text(strip=True))


Yes, I found a div whose class is called text bold from there and extra values.
if i use html parser , i find only one str - " Cheki_FNS ", but if I use xml , i get correct text.
I think I'll have to write a string loop to get rid of the extra ones, or I can use regular expressions, which will help ignore the extra text.

Is there something in structure or in text that is constant? e.g. 'Cash receipt received:'
